# how to forward a zend 2 action

Tags: php, zend-framework, redirect

I am new to this forum. Please help me solve my issue.

my controller is 'ClientController' and action to which I want to forward is 'EditClient'. I want to pass my current request to this action with the parameter 'id' = 23.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$forward = $this->forward()->dispatch('Client', array('action' => 'EditClient'));
return array(
    'id' => 21,
    'Client'=> $forward,
);
```

refer official document [HERE](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html)

example at the github [HERE](https://gist.github.com/holyshared/3192233)

Comment: thanks, using what I have to replace 'foo'? I have added my case above in question. Can you replace using my real variables in your answer please?

Answer (score 0):

```
In zend project your action URL is Client/EditClient/23
**Here is code sample.....**
<?php echo $this->url('Client', array('action'=>'EditClient', 'id' => 23));?>
```

Comment: This one also correct. I chosen the above one because he was the first to reply.

Comment: You can use this code: <?php echo $this->url('Client', array('action'=>'EditClient', 'id' => 23));?>